# Как определить, какая цветовая тема выбрана в ОС?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как определить, какая цветовая тема выбрана в ОС (темная/светлая/кастомная)?

Хотел сделать возможность самостоятельного изменения цветовой темы в приложении за счет определения выбранной цветовой темы в ОС средствами Qt, но не могу понять как.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334674/how-to-detect-windows-10-light-dark-mode-in-win32-application/51336913

Comment: @user7860670 Мне бы кроссплатформенное решение, а не только Windows. И то, средствами Qt, если это возможно вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить основные цвета текущей схемы можно с использованием класса [QPalette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#QPalette).
`QGuiApplication::palette` создает палитру в соответствии с текущей схемой ОС, если только через аргументы командной строки не была выбрана другая схема, или не была установлена специальная схема или палитры, вызовами `setPalette`, `setStyleSheet`, `setStyle`.

Пример:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    QPalette basePalette;
    QColor baseColor =  basePalette.base().color();
    QColor newBase= QColor::fromRgbF( 1-baseColor.redF(), 1-baseColor.greenF(), 1-baseColor.blueF() );
    
    a.setPalette( QPalette( newBase ) );
    
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr,"test", "Test of base color invert...");
    
    return a.exec();
}
```